# Unable to retrieve unicode field from mysql to php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database table where i want to store and retrieve in English and Nepali Language. I have a following configuration:
Type: InnoDB
Database collation : utf8_general_ci

**Column name**: Title_ne 
**Data Type**: text 
**Column Collation**: utf8_unicode_ci

Now when i insert data into Title_ne field using phpmyadmin and provide something like नमस्कार using Google Nepali input for Windows, it is inserted and displayed correctly while querying in phpmyadmin. But, while i query this from php and try to display it in php page, only ???????? is displayed. Am i doing something wrong on table design or inserting data? What is wrong, please provide your suggestions.

नमस्कार is a way of Greeting in Nepal.

Comment: your entire rendering pipeline has to be utf8. php<->db connection, db tables, html page, etc... you probably have a stage somewhere where it ISN'T set for utf8, and getting mangled text from it. I'm guessing it's your DB connection.

Comment: I am adding one page on this project and I am using existing DB Helper that is working perfectly with other class. But, for other table and php where Nepali is perfectly rendered, their table entry looks like à¤µà¤¿à¤¦à¥à¤¯à¤¾ à¤‰à¤ªà¤¾à¤§à¥à¤¯à¤¾à¤¯ à¤¨à¥...
For both english and Nepali field.

Comment: Query 'SET NAMES utf8' to the DB and it should be alright. As Marc B said, something went wrong in the connection, this query just after connecting to the DB usually solves it.